# OkHttp Android JSonObject casting exception

Tags: android, instagram-api, okhttp, httpsurlconnection

When I use OkHttp to post I get a response like this (Instagram api)

```
{"access_token":"2222222.22222.2222222","user":{"username":"xxx","bio":"","website":"","profile_picture":"https:\/\/instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net\/profiles\/anonymousUser.jpg","full_name":"Test","id":"222222"}}
```

which I am unable to cast to a JsonObject (I think it is because of the weird way the urls are formatted).

But when I use HttpsUrlConnection everything works fine.

**OkHTTP**

```
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    public static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN
            = MediaType.parse("text/plain");
```

//then in a function

```
 String postBody="client_id="+Application.INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID
                    +"&client_secret="+Application.INSTAGRAM_SECRET_KEY
                    +"&grant_type=authorization_code"
                    +"&redirect_uri=" +Application.CALLBACKURL
                    +"&code=" + SharedPrefHelper.getSharedPerferenceData(context, SharedPrefHelper.SHARED_PREFERENCE_KEY_INSTAGRAM_CODE, "");
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(Application.TOKENURL)
                    .post(RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN,postBody))
                    .build();
```

I use response.body.string() in the callback method to get the string and cast it to JsonObject.

```
  if (response.code() == 200) { 
try { 
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string()); 
} catch (JSONException e) { 

 } 
}
```

How to fix this ?
ERROR :

```
org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Comment: if (response.code() == 200) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.i("XXX",e.toString());
                        }

                    }

Comment: This is the string I am getting... {"access_token":"2222222.22222.2222222","user":{"username":"xxx","bio":"","website":"","profile_picture":"https:\/\/instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net\/profiles\/anonymousUser.jpg","full_name":"Test","id":"222222"}}

Comment: I am getting the string that I posted above and right after logging the string. I use the JSONObject casting.... Something weird with that url with escape sequences maybe ?

Comment: By not logging response.body().string() and using it directly with JSONObject constructor .... code works. May be you can use it once. Solved the issue though .... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use response.body().string() only once. I was calling it twice. First for logging the response and then again for json casting.

Comment: Ok, so before my comment, why your app still has error?

Comment: Because I was logging it already. Solution is you can't use response.body().string() twice. It is not even a null pointer exception.

Comment: `use response.body().string() twice` will not throw jsonexception

Comment: First for logging and then when I was using the string (response.body().string()) with JsonObject.

Answer (score -1):

**First thing:**

You are probably getting a blank response. Its not null but the response is empty. So you are getting this error and not a `NullPointerException`

Have you logged it before converting in JSON? Checked it.

**Second Thing:**

You may have to try with `GET` if you are used `POST` currently or Vice Versa.